# I'm running my flutter app and got this error

Tags: flutter, dart, dart-null-safety

/C:/src/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/flutter_pagewise-2.0.3/lib/flutter_pagewise.dart:510:23: Error: Method 'removeWhere' cannot be called on 'List?' because it is potentially null.

- 'List' is from 'dart:core'.
  Try calling using ?. instead.
  this._loadedItems.removeWhere(test);
  ^^^^^^^^^^^

Comment: Can you include sample code-snippet that will reproduce the issue

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 1):

Based on your error, It is possible to get null on `_loadedItems`. You can do a null check 1st like

```dart
  List? _loadedItems;

  if (_loadedItems != null) {
    _loadedItems.removeWhere((element) => ...);
  }
```

More about [understanding-null-safety](https://dart.dev/null-safety/understanding-null-safety)